# Change cell value then the will follow vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a code that automatically fill series in column A.
My worksheet is protected with a password
and can only edit specific cells.

column A is the basis or the number of requested data.
Example:

```
Gee-2019-000
Gee-2019-001 ...
```

I just want the value in A2 which is **Gee-2019-000** to be changed. If I enter **Gee-2020-000** on A2 then the rest will follow.
Example:

```
Gee-2020-000
Gee-2020-001 ...
```

Note: only A2 is allowed to edit for the requested number.

Here's my code. I don't actually know how to do it, but I tried something just in case it will work, but it didn't.

```
Dim target As Excel.Range
    With target
        If .Address = Range("A2").Address Then
            .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A1222"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Did the formula fill the column perhaps with the same value? Have you tried to manually use the drag fill on a blank sheet without password protection. The xlFillDefault can not find the pattern. Even after coercing the subsequent row to ...002, selecting both cells and drag filing the two together, there is no pattern, This is because there are numbers and letters mixed together in one cell. If the pattern is known, implement a loop to create it. Also, the range is 1221 rows (2-1222) but the pattern only allows for 1000 (000-999). This is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest Macro will fill destination Cells with increment, considering the Source Value.*

- Copy & Paste this Macro as Standard Module.

  ```
  Sub IncremntValue()

  Dim code As String
  code = InputBox("Enter Code")

  Range("B1").Value = code
  Range("B2").Formula = "=LEFT(B1,9)&TEXT(ROW(A1),""000"")"
  Range("B2").Select
  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B200"), Type:=xlFillDefault

  End Sub
  ```

*You get result like this:*

- I'm assuming the INPUT value is `Gee-2019-000`.

[image]

*As soon you modify source value in B1 or Input any new code, you get this:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- Use of **INPUTBOX** makes the code more competent & faster.
- The Formula I've used `=LEFT(B1,9)&TEXT(ROW(A1),""000"")"` *is
  situational, which may vary if the Code 
  composition in cell `B1` changes.*
- Adjust Cell reference in the Formula as needed.

**Edited:**

To automate *Auto Fill event* better you use commands wrapped with **Worsheet Change Event**, rather than a Simple Macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1")) Is Nothing Then


Range("A2").Formula = "=LEFT($A$1,9)&TEXT(ROW(A1),""000"")"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A20"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good approach, however, I gleaned from the OP code that the solution was targeted for the Sheet's Worksheet_Change module. This would create a circular reference (as well as _Calculate). Perhaps just manually entering the formula into cell A3 and drag filling the remainder of the rows. Once and done. Any edits to A2 would be updated in the rest of the cells by their formulas. `=LEFT(A2,9)&TEXT(ROW(A1),"000")`. Row A1 is not a typo, it forces the numbering to begin from one in cell A3 and assumes A2 was zero.

Comment: @TedD.,, thanks for observation, **it's fully a situational  Macro** and the need was to handle String (Code) rather than number, would much easier. I've tried the Macro on `A11` onwards and it's working, using `ROW(A1)` helps to increment.

Comment: The fact that the macro provided in this answer would not automatically execute, but instead be manually run (situationally), was exactly my point. From the context of the attempted OP solution, it seemed the desired solution would run automatically. This answer is good because once the macro has been executed manually one time, all subsequent edits to A2 (in the OP context) will not require the use of the macro (as the formula is now populating A3:A1222).

Comment: Probably better to use an absolute address, `$A$2`, in the formula `"=LEFT($A$2,9)$TEXT(ROW(A1),""000"")"` so autofill does not create dependency on dependency on dependency ... (A4="Left(A**3**..." A5="Left(A**4**..." and so on)

Comment: @TedD.,, check the edited part now I've included another Macro with **Worksheet Change Event** ☺

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A1222"), Type:=xlFillDefault` with:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim prefixVal As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
prefixVal = Left(Range("A2"), InStrRev(Range("A2"),"-"))
For Each r In Range("A3:A1222")
    r.Value = prefixVal & Format(i, "000")
    i = i + 1
Next r
```